# GroupBy cannot infer type arguments from usage

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code to calculate the most common occurance of a certain height. However, I cannot seem to do it like this as is evident by the following error. Would anyone be able to tell me how I can resolve this? The inputted variable `lines` is of type `IEnumerable<(Vector4D, Vector4D)>`.

```
Error    CS0411    The type arguments for method 
'Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>?)' 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

```cs
lines.Select(line => (Y: line.Item1.Y, Vector: line.Item1 - line.Item2))
   .Where(pair => Math.Abs(Vector4D.DotProduct(new Vector4D(1, 0, 0, 0), pair.Vector)) > 0.9)
   .GroupBy(pair => pair.Y, new CompareWithTolerance((float)verticalTolerance))
   .Select(group => (Y: group.Key, Length: group.Sum(x => x.Vector.Length))
   .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Y * pair.Length));
```

```cs
    internal class CompareWithTolerance : EqualityComparer<float>
    {
        private float _tolerance;

        public CompareWithTolerance(float tolerance)
        {
            _tolerance = tolerance;
        }

        public override bool Equals(float a, float b)
        {
            return Math.Abs(a - b) < _tolerance;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(float f)
        {
            return f.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking `Y` isn't a `float`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar from hovering over it, it appears to be a double. casting it to a float does seem to fix it... Rather simple, but I must have looked past it entirely. This does however cause a different issue (unrelated to the first) in that OrderByDescending does not work on (float Y, double Length) which is the result of the GroupBy query

Comment: The object may be null.

Comment: For GroupBy, *first* GetHashCode is called and then *only* for equal hashcodes, that Equals is used. So two floats that are "about equal" should have the same hashcode

Comment: What ordered would you expect for `(float Y, double Length)` tuple? You should use `ThenByDescending`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback I received, it seems I forgot to change the type of the comparing value to float, which was causing it to throw an error.

The resulting issue I presented in my response was easily fixed simply by placing some additional brackets.